# Influence of the Third Party Developer Investment (monthly cost)

Tags: android, game-studio-tycoon-3

[Game Studio Tycoon 3 is an Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msherwin.GameStudioTycoon3&hl=en) game where you can build and sell your own games and hardware (console, handheld...).

The problem with this game is that many things are not "explained" in the tutorial and you need to "try and retry" before you understand how something will affect a game.

The Hardware is not even included in the tutorial, so there is no info at all about it.

How will the Third Part Developer Investment cost will affect the selling of the hardware? Even more important, what IS that?

[image]

Comment: For future reference, you have enough rep to make new tags.  Don't be shy to make a new one! I did this time for you.

Comment: @TimmyJim Thank you! I didn't notice that I had rep enough for that. EDIT: Create tag is 300 reps! People probably think I'm lazy!!!